# Why is exec-shield protection not on by default? (What are the pros of having it off?)

Tags: linux, security, centos

I am working in CentOS 5, I was wondering why exec-shield isn't on by default? I found a bunch of articles on how to enable and disable it as well - but nothing answering why anyone would want it off. Any cons to turning it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exec-shield can break some programs, depending on how they were written.  Eg, look at [this reference](https://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-test-list/2003-September/msg00773.html) from a Red Hat mailing list:

> 2 enables every exec-shield unconditionally (modulo exec-shield-randomize) regardless of the type of executable loaded.  This WILL break programs, and is generally discouraged, but you've got enough rope to hang yourself and break your Loki games.  :-)

I'm guessing that the CentOS maintainers are making the judgment that it is better to ship an OS that runs all programs and is less secure, rather than having users try to diagnose failures in old programs.